python subprocess modify incoming stream and printing it live
Note: This seems like a solved problem, but I couldn't find a solution.
I have some command line utility I need to use. For example something like
import sys, time

for i in range(3):
    print('working')
    time.sleep(.3)
    
print('upsi', file=sys.stderr)

print('the end')
exit(123)

I want to call it (something like subprocess.run(['python', 'test.py'])), but I also need to add some custom metadata to the beginning of each line. For example:
[Line:1,Time:04:34] working
[Line:2,Time:04:34] working
[Line:3,Time:04:35] working
[Line:4,Time:04:35,ERROR=True] upsi
[Line:5,Time:04:35] the end

[RETURN CODE] 123

[END]


I need the output to be 'live' meaning I can't just collect the finished output and add the meta data somehow (Timestamps also wouldn't work this way).
Ideally I could just pass two functions for stdout and stderr which take in a byte-stream and somehow print the desired output, but I don't know how I can apply these functions to the process.
The only solution I could think of was to point both stdout and stderr to external files and read them. But this seems very clunky to me.
Note, that I need to both watch stdout and stderr.
Bonus points for a non-blocking solution.

You can't do this with subprocess.run(), as it doesn't return control to you until the command has finished executing.  You need subprocess.Popen() instead, which allows you to read from the process's stdout and stderr.  The problem is that you can't tell which one needs to be read from next - so you either need to merge them together (an option in the Popen() call), or read at least one of the channels from a separate thread.
